# Value in a map contains another map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

For example below map name is `TEST`:

```
{
  name : 1
  place : 2
  others : {marks : 100 , rank : 200 }
}
```

I am unable to get value of others as a separate map.

```
Map<String,Object> final = TEST.get('others'); //It throws class cast exception
```

How to get value of others in a separate map?

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace please.

Comment: I can't tell anything from this code. Also `'others'` will never compile.

Comment: This looks like a (malformed) JSON object; in this case why not use a JSON library allowing JSON traversal, such as Jackson?

Comment: Map<String,Object> others = (Map<String, Object>) TEST.get("others"); must work. If it is not than kindly post your exception stack trace you might having some different issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the test map in such a way

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> Test = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
```

then you can get the value using `for(Entry<String,Map<String,String>> testsample : Test.entryset())` then u can use `testsample.entryvalue` to get the map inside it.

Comment: Not like that, since he has multiple type of objects in map